# How to hide/show drop down list content in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have two options in the list (pickup/drop), what I want is that when user select pickup from the list the (pick date /pick time ) fields appear and (drop date / drop time) fields gets hide and vice versa.

```
<html>
<script>
             function hideDiv()
      {
           document.getElementById("div1").style.display='none'; 
           document.getElementById("div2").style.display='block'; 
      }
            function showDiv()
     {
          document.getElementById("div1").style.display='block'; 
               document.getElementById("div2").style.display='none'; 
      }

</script>
    <body onload="hideDiv()">
        <form method = "post">
            <H1>Please enter the following details below.</H1>
            <table border="1" align="left" cellpadding ="30" cellspacing="5">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                        Employid <input type="text" name="sid" /> 
                        Supervisor <input type="text" name="ssup" />
                        Department <input type="text" name="sdept" />

                            <label>Select your option</label>
                            <select id="myList">
                       <option value="1" onselect="showDiv() name="pp">Pickup</option>
                      <option value="2" onselect="hideDiv()name="dd">Drop</option>
                            </select>
                     <div id="div2">
                        Pickup date <input type="date" name="pte" />
                        Pickup time <input type="time"  name="ptm" /></br>
                 </div>
                 <div id="div1">
                        Drop date <input type="date" name="dte" />
                        Drop time <input type="time"  name="dtm" /></br>
                  </div>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /></br>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table border="1" align="right" cellpadding ="30" cellspacing="2">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                        <a href="myprojectallrequest.jsp">View all requests</a></br>
                        <a href="myprojectallrequest.jsp">View pending requests</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You'll need javascript to do this

Answer (score 1):

First don't use **paragraph tag** here.

Use div tag and place,

```
Pickup date <input type="date" name="pte" >
Pickup time<input type= time  name= ptm >
```

and

```
Drop date <input type="date" name="dte" >
Drop time<input type= time  name= dtm >
```

in a seperate div tags namely pickup and drop.

Give needed styles with

> display:none;

Now in javascript, use On select event on selected item and change the selected div id's display as block.Like

```
function onsElect()
{
document.getElementById("pickup").style.display=block;
}
```

Please expand the functionality based on your requirements.

Comment: I have updated my post (included the div tag).  when the page loads drop date/drop time is hidden but when i select drop from the list the showDiv() function doesnt work. pls tell me what am i doing wrong.

Comment: Hey you should not use like this, <option value="1" onselect="showDiv() name="pp">Pickup</option>
<option value="2" onselect="hideDiv() name="dd">Drop</option>
Use "showdiv()"...It 'll work

Comment: i tried by changing the case to showdiv() instead of showDiv() but it still doesn't work... (i am using chrome browser)

Comment: Can anyone provide the answer pls ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
Pickup date <input class="type_pickup typetoggle" type="date" name="pte">
Pickup time <input class="type_pickup typetoggle" type="time" name="ptm">
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#myList').change( function() {
    $('.typetoggle').hide();
    if ($(this).val() == "1")
        $('.type_pickup').show();
    if ($(this).val() == "2")
        $('.type_drop').show();
});
</script>
```

Comment: May be your script is correct. Explain every variable in detail manner. Hence people will understand your code.

Answer (score 0):

To add dynamics like this you will have to use javascript.
You could go for something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/JqLk2/).

```
function toggle() {
    var foo = document.getElementById('foo'),
        bar = document.getElementById('bar'),
        foodiv = document.getElementById('foo-div'),
        bardiv = document.getElementById('bar-div');
    if (foo.checked) {
        foodiv.className = '';
        bardiv.className = 'hidden';
    } else {
        foodiv.className = 'hidden';
        bardiv.className = '';
    }
}
```

A simple js function that will change the class for elements from `hidden` to none.
If that is all you desire, then there's no need for using a library like jQuery. If you want to use jQuery you can learn more about it and all of it's great features [here](http://try.jquery.com/).