# Dropdown that hides on click outside of the menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I've got a simple dropdown script and I want it to hide all open dropdowns on a click outside of the menu. But it does not seem to work, does anyone know why?

You can find it here: http://codepen.io/dr-potato/pen/rLleC?editors=101

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li class="Navigation-listItem is-dropdown">
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <ul class="Navigation-list is-dropdown is-hidden">
        <li>Johnny</li>
        <li>Julie</li>
        <li>Jamie</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="Navigation-listItem is-dropdown">
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    <ul class="Navigation-list is-dropdown is-hidden">
        <li>Johnny</li>
        <li>Julie</li>
        <li>Jamie</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.Navigation-list {
    display: block;
}

.Navigation-list.is-hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.Navigation-listItem').click(function() {
      $(this).children('.Navigation-list.is-dropdown').toggleClass('is-hidden');
    });
});

/* Anything that gets to the document
   will hide the dropdown */
$(document).click(function(){
  $(".Navigation-listItem.is-dropdown").addClass('is-hidden');
});

/* Clicks within the dropdown won't make
   it past the dropdown itself */
$(".Navigation-listItem.is-dropdown").click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: your dropdown doesn't seem to appear.

Comment: @Gaurav: Sorry, there was a spelling mistake in the JS

Comment: @Gaurav, however the problem still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rv4Ng/1/)

**jQuery Code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.Navigation-listItem').click(function () {
        $(this).children('.Navigation-list.is-dropdown').toggleClass('is-hidden');
    });


    /* Anything that gets to the document
   will hide the dropdown */
    $(document).on('click', function (event) {
        if ($(event.target).closest('#menu').length == false) {
            $(".Navigation-list.is-dropdown").addClass('is-hidden');
        }
    });

    /* Clicks within the dropdown won't make
   it past the dropdown itself */
    $(".Navigation-listItem.is-dropdown ").click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

With help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10851375/2260614)

Comment: you may want to extend this to only enable the 'click' event while you know the menu to be open. otherwise every click goes through this handler, which while probably negligible isn't ideal

Comment: why on earth would you deliberately do 'length == false'

Comment: @Simon_Weaver Have a look [at the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10851375/2260614) for why I have used `length == false`. And I am not sure of how to '___enable the 'click' event while you know the menu to be open___'. Any help..!!?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the display property of your dropdown in this manner. This is just a rough code.

```
                       if(dropDownShow.css('display') != 'block'){
                            dropDownShow.css('display', 'block');
                            dropDownShow.css('position', 'absolute');

                        }
                        else{
                            dropDownShow.css('display', 'none');
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

With the info you gave and the codepen I can't see it working, but I suppose that $(document).click(function() to hide won't work because the drop down is inside the document so when you click it, it'll disappear. I recommend you to see this post [How to hide/show drop down list content in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143141/how-to-hide-show-drop-down-list-content-in-html).

Comment: There was a spelling mistake in the JS, I corrected it.

Comment: Well that didn't solve my question however, so any help would still be appreciated :).

Comment: So sorry, I'm not a designer and would take me lot of time to solve it. Hope someone else's faster.